# Finding representation matrix of $M$*$(K_5)$ above $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, matroids

Finding representation matrix of $M$*$(K_5)$ above $\mathbb F_2$.

$M$*$(K_5)$ is the dual matroid representing the graph $K_5$, that is, a complete graph with  5 vertices.

How do I solve this? We've never been shown this type of questions @class.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking for here. Do you understand what $M(K_5)$ and $M^*(K_5)$ are in the first place, or are you asking for the representation matrix only? Can you find the representing matrix for $M(K_5)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matroid of rank $m$ over a ground set of $n$ elements is representable over a field $F$, then it is representable by a matrix of the form $[I^m | B ]$, where $B$ is a $m \times (n-m)$ matrix over $F$. Also, any matrix representation can be transformed to one of this form by performing elementary row operations and (possibly) deleting rows. To see why, look at the observations after Definition 2 in [this lecture](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18438F09/lec8.pdf). By Theorem 2 of the same lecture, if a matroid $M$ is representable in a field $F$ by a matrix $[I^m | B]$, then its dual matroid $M^\ast$ is also representable over $F$, by the matrix $[B^t | I^{n-m} ]$.

Moreover, by Lemma 1 of the lecture, the [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) of a graph $G$ corresponds to a representation matrix of the graphic matroid of $G$ over $\mathbf{F}_2$.

So, to find a representation matrix of $M^\ast(K_5)$ over $\mathbf{F}_2$, we start with a representation matrix of $M(K_5)$ over $\mathbf{F}_2$, given by an incidence matrix of the graph:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right] $$

We perform row operations to obtain the form $[I^m | B]$. As the rank of $M(K_5)$ is $4$, we must delete one row, and it suffices to delete the first one to reach the desired form.

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right] $$

Then, the representation matrix of $M^\ast(K_5)$, by the above remarks, is given by

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right] $$